# Mongodb how to cancel a --fork without mongod service 'option'

Tags: mongodb, linux, log, wiredtiger, mongodb-3.6

I am currently having issues with `sudo service mongod start/stop/etc` so instead I have been running mongo with `sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --bind_ip_all  --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --auth --fork` but I received errors if I wanted to change any of those `--options` (such as `--bind_ip_all` to something more specific) to something else and I am assuming it is because the `--fork` has never been cancelled.

To summarize, how do you cancel `mongod` through the cli so that I can update the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just kill the process. `killall mongod`

To check that you don't have any mongod process running anymore, you can use `ps -ef|grep mongod|grep -v grep`  or just `pgrep mongod`. With that latter, if you get pid number (as answer), mongod is still running

Answer (score 1):

The `--fork` is a flag to tell `mongod` to run as a background process, rather than as an active process which blocks the shell.

Mongod is the main daemon process for MongoDB. It's the core unit of the database, handling connections, requests, and the most important part of it, persisting of data, or writing your data at a disk. A daemon is a program or a process that's meant to be run and not interacted with in a direct manner.

By convention, daemons have a "d" appended to the end of their name, hence the name `mongod`. when we run `mongod`, we don't interact with it directly. Instead, our application utilizes a driver to communicate. The user interaction is at the application level and the driver handles all the nitty gritty details of communication with `mongod`.

Through mongo shell run the below command:

```
>killall mongod
```

It will kill your all background running pid of `mongod` process.